# Build path errors in "App Engine Connected Android Project" created using wizard

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Launch wizard to create "App Engine Connected Android Project"
2. Use a *custom project location* instead of default location

Result:
Generated Android project can't find endpoint-libs, resulting in build path errors.

Generated app-engine project is in default location, not in custom location

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?

- Android SDK Tools 23.02;
- GPE 3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid the problem is to use the default location for the generated projects.

Bug reported to Google at http://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=290